# return value from method without creating an object

Tags: java, class, methods

Ok so I have a large structure of classes that looks something like [**THIS**](http://uaa.ryannixon.com/uploads/cs201/scReference.pdf)

Its for school and my instructor likes Starcraft, so lets just go with it.

Anyway I have a method in the *GeneratorBuilding* Class that is supposed to be able to instantiate a new *Marine* Object. However I need to know how many resources a *Marine* object costs.

I have an abstract int method in the abstract *Unit* class called unitCost(). Then the *Marine* class overrides this method and returns a value like 50.

I am looking for a way to have my *GeneratorBuilding* class get the return value for the unitCost() method in the *Marine* class without calling any specific Marine object.

I know that I could probably create a marine object and then ask how much it costs and then if I dont have the resources I would delete the object instead of pushing it into an ArrayList. But this seems almost like a workaround.

EDIT: The whole point is to be able to let ALL of my concrete classes inherit and override the UnitCost() method. So I could make it static but that ruins the whole point of an inheritance structure...

EDIT2: Since there was a request for example code (not exactly hard to imagine)

```
public void makeMarine(){

    //uses resources and throws exception etc if there are not enough resources
    Game.useResources(Marine.unitCost());

    //creates a marine
    Game.addMarine();
}
```

Comment: Make the method static and then call it without having to instantiate an object? Not really sure what you need since there's zero code posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by declaring a specifically named static field in each class, and getting it through *reflection*}.

Suppose your classes look like this:

```
class ClassNumber1 {
    public static final int cost = 123;
}
class ClassNumber2 {
    public static final int cost = 321;
}
```

Then you can obtain their `cost` fields like this:

```
public static <T> int getCost(Class<T> cl) throws Exception {
    // This is oversimplified: you need to check that the class
    // indeed has a field called "cost" by null-checking the return value
    // of getField(), verifying your cast, catching exceptions, and so on.
    // But this will work in a "closed" system, when you know for sure
    // that an int constant field does exist:
    return (int)cl.getField("cost").get(null);
}
```

You call the method as follows:

```
System.out.println(getCost(ClassNumber1.class));
System.out.println(getCost(ClassNumber2.class));
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/5YU5Yc).

Comment: Again... Im trying to work with overriding abstract methods. If there is no possible way to do this with abstract methods then I will use a static method. Im well aware of how do do it with static methods, its the abstract method that is throwing me off

Comment: @KroniK907 There is absolutely, positively, no way of using abstract methods (or methods that implement interfaces, that's the same thing) without instantiating objects. Note that the approach above does not rely on static methods, only on static constants.

Comment: Thanks! that was my main question!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a good, abstract OO solution to this problem, you should use the *[Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)*.

Basically, this means you create a "factory" class whose only job is to create a specific type of unit. The nice thing about factory classes is that you can create an interface to represent your entire set of factories, and then pass around instances of the factories—which isn't really something you can do with normal class constructors.

A common pattern (which I would recommend here) is to use *[Anonymous Inner Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)* with your abstract factory class or interface to create single instances of the "factory" for each unit type.

Here's a bit of example code to get you started:

```
/**
 * Abstract class for Starcraft units
 */
public abstract class AUnit {
  // . . .
}

/**
 * Abstract factory for creating Starcraft units
 */
public abstract class AUnitFactory {
  public abstract int unitCost();
  public abstract AUnit createUnit();
}

public class Marine extends AUnit {

  public static final int COST = 50;

  /**
   * Using an anonymous inner class to create an
   * AUnitFactory instance for Marines
   */
  public static final FACTORY = new AUnitFactory() {
    public int unitCost() { return COST; }
    public AUnit createUnit() { return new Marine(); }
  }

  // . . .

}

public class Zergling extends AUnit {

  public static final int COST = 25;

  /**
   * Using an anonymous inner class to create an
   * AUnitFactory instance for Zerglings
   */
  public static final FACTORY = new AUnitFactory() {
    public int unitCost() { return COST; }
    public AUnit createUnit() { return new Zergling(); }
  }

  // . . .

}

/**
 * Starcraft game!
 */
public class Game {

  public addUnit(Player player, AUnitFactory unitFactory) {
    // Get unit's cost
    int cost = unitFactory.unitCost();
    // Now deduct it from the player's resources
    // . . .
    // Create the unit
    AUnit unit = unitFactory.createUnit();
    // Now add the unit to the game for the given player
    // . . .
  }

  // . . .

}
```

Now you could do something like `Game.addUnit(player1, Zergling.FACTORY)` or `Game.addUnit(player2, Marine.FACTORY)`.

The nice thing is that you can pass the *FACTORY* instances around since they're just objects of type `AUnitFactory`. This means you could do something like have a *combo box* to select a unit type, and then a button which creates one of whichever unit type is currently selected in the combo box when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what class methods are for. In a class method, unitCost() is a method of the Marine class itself (i.e. static public int UnitCost()), so you can call Marine.unitCost(), rather than m =new Marine() and then m.UnitCost().

Cool instructor. Wish I had one when I was taking OO.

Comment: Btw, tell him to add the Protoss in there, as well. That will get you a few bonus points.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that you cannot inherit and override static methods.

Comment: I guess that works, but the problem is then its not abstract and inherited from the Unit class. to do that for several of my methods would ruin the point of an inheritance structure? IDK Im just learning :P